# How to create an invalid QModelIndex?

Tags: c++, qt, qstandarditemmodel, qmodelindex

I am implementing a function which searchs a `QModelIndex` based on a `QString` input.
However if I cannot find this index, the function should retun an invalid index.
My model is a `QStandardItemModel`.

Is is okay to return `invisibleRootItem()->index()` as an invalid index?
In the [qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#invisibleRootItem) is noted that it will always creates an invalid index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the default constructor of [`QModelIndex`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html)(e.g. `return QModelIndex()`) which is null as indicated in [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#QModelIndex):

> [`QModelIndex::QModelIndex()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html)
>  Creates a new empty model index. This type
> of model index is used to indicate that the position in the model **is
> invalid.**

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>